# Why so many sp_procedure_params_100_managed calls?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, profiling

I'm profiling my application (Analyze -> Launch Performance Wizard...) and am looking at the Tier Interactions view which shows how long the application spends on database calls.

I've got one line which shows:

```
[myDb].[sys].[sp_procedure_params_100_managed]
```

called 73 times.

What's going on?

Comment: It would appear the parameters are not cached, based on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704794/enterprise-library-caching-parameters-on-stored-procs)

Comment: @billinkc - I'll take a peak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Enterprise Framework, and it sounds like EF is making a boatload of "DiscoverParameters()" calls:

[Enterprise library caching parameters on stored procs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704794/enterprise-library-caching-parameters-on-stored-procs)

Here's one possible workaround (from the above link):

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/03/CachingStoredProcedureParameters.aspx

Comment: I'm not using entlib though :(.  I'll take a look at the links though.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I need to do something with the code using SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters;

Comment: davidhayen.com link is broken. Copy at archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20070210091538/http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/03/CachingStoredProcedureParameters.aspx